# How to get all issues of project via Jira REST Java Client?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I'm trying to get all issues of project and then find which are done, but I don't know how.
I connected user to Jira and than wanted to get all of his project and all of issue on him. Then I want to find, which issues from that are done. Can anybody help me, please?

I've got this:

```java
Iterable <BasicProject> allProj;
this.yourUsername = userName;
this.yourPassword = password;

this.jiraServerUri = new URI("https://applifting.atlassian.net");
this.factory = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory();;
this.restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, yourUsername, yourPassword);
final NullProgressMonitor pm = new NullProgressMonitor();
allProj = this.restClient.getProjectClient().getAllProjects(pm);

for(Iterator<BasicProject> i = allProj.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    BasicProject proj = i.next();
    Project ActualProject = this.restClient.getProjectClient().getProject(proj.getKey(), pm);
    ComponentRestClient cm =

}
```

I thought in this `for` cycle I should get all issues when I have all project.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a JQL that specifies your search criteria, you can invoke that: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e2716

For a code example, please take a look here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/192961/answers/4049301

A working example: (also here: http://pastebin.com/WUMZ0vZa)

```
package com.example.jirasandbox;

import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClient;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClientFactory;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.BasicProject;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.SearchResult;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.User;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory;
import com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promise;
import java.net.URI;

public class CustomJiraRestClient {

    private static final String JIRA_URL = "http://jira-dev:8080";
    private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME = "admin";
    private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "admin";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Construct the JRJC client
        System.out.println(String.format("Logging in to %s with username '%s' and password '%s'", JIRA_URL, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD));
        JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
        URI uri = new URI(JIRA_URL);
        JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD);

        // Invoke the JRJC Client
        Promise<User> promise = client.getUserClient().getUser("admin");
        User user = promise.claim();

        for (BasicProject project : client.getProjectClient().getAllProjects().claim()) {
            System.out.println(project.getKey() + ": " + project.getName());
        }

        Promise<SearchResult> searchJqlPromise = client.getSearchClient().searchJql("project = MYPURRJECT AND status in (Closed, Completed, Resolved) ORDER BY assignee, resolutiondate");

        for (Issue issue : searchJqlPromise.claim().getIssues()) {
            System.out.println(issue.getSummary());
        }

        // Print the result
        System.out.println(String.format("Your admin user's email address is: %s\r\n", user.getEmailAddress()));

        // Done
        System.out.println("Example complete. Now exiting.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, in that working example the String URL is my jira, right? And Promise<SearchResult> searchJqlPromise = client.getSearchClient().searchJql("project = MYPURRJECT AND status in (Closed, Completed, Resolved) ORDER BY assignee, resolutiondate"); - how should you know how to specify that?

Comment: Your connection to jira is in `this.restClient`object . Use `restClient.getSearchClient().searchJql(JQLquery)` function with JQL query to get issues you want. To get JQL query log into Jira and in issue navigator search for issues you want, then switch to Advanced search using JQL and there is your JQL query.

Comment: Yes, the JIRA_URL points to your jira. Also, @ThePavolC gets it right, you can issue JQL queries on the site there. "Issues" menu on the top, then "Search for Issues" menuitem, then click the "Advanced" link.

Comment: You mean to include the stuff that resides now in pastebin?

Comment: Hi @Koshinae - Do we definitely need REST api setup or Can I just use Jira rest java client jar and get the jira issues? We are using JIRA cloud. And Do I need to use only jira admin credentials? Please help me. I am new to this feature.

Comment: You can use any active user (AFAIK). Also, the new approach is the REST way, so you should try both :)

Comment: I'm getting 'incompatible types: com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory cannot be converted to com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.JiraRestClientFactory'.

Comment: Hey @Koshinae, Here u have provided username and password. Can we call api using only personal api token of jira?